# SOAP server 1.1 sending response using content type defined for 1.2?

Tags: wcf, soap, soap-client

1. I tried sending a SOAP1.2 request to a server and received following exception

   > System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The envelope version of the incoming message (Soap11 (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/)) does not 
   >   match that of the encoder (Soap12 (http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope)). Make sure the binding is configured with the same version as the expected messages.

On analyzing the traffic through wireshark, I see the response envelope as http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ and request envelope as http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope

2. Again I tried sending message to same server using SOAP 1.1 and got following exception

   > System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type application/soap
   >   +xml of the response message does not match the content type of the binding 
   >   (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the 
   >   IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly.

Based on above 2 logs, can I conclude the remote server is using SOAP1.1 and sending the response using content type defined for SOAP1.2 which is application/soap+xml? Is it the right implementation of SOAP specification?

Code was generated using Service reference from WSDL. Following is the code snippet:

```
Test3.ServiceReference1.SoapRqst client = new Test3.ServiceReference1.SoapRqstClient();
RepRequest rqst = new RepRequest();
RepResponse op = client.getReply(rqst);
string responseSting = op.Body.respMsg;
Console.Out.Write(responseSting);
```

Client side service model:

Service binding For SOAP 1.1

```
   <system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="<>"  />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="<>"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="<>"
            contract="<>" name="<>" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Service binding for SOAP 1.2

```
   <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="">
            <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
            <httpTransport />
        </binding>
    </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
    <endpoint address="<>"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="<>"
        contract="<>" name="<>" />
</client>
```

Comment: Your title does not describe your problem. How many questions on [so] could be described as "SOAP Response Error"? Please edit your title so that it describes your specific problem.

Comment: Great. Now, how did you send the two requests? Please include small pieces of code that show how you made the requests.

Comment: Used WSDL to generate Service reference after that is 4-5 line code<br/><br/>  Test3.ServiceReference1.SoapRqst client = new Test3.ServiceReference1.SoapRqstClient(); <br/><br/> 
RepRequest rqst = new RepRequest(); <br/> <br/> 
RepResponse op = client.getReply(rqst);<br/> <br/> 
string responseSting = op.Body.respMsg;<br/> <br/> 
Console.Out.Write(responseSting); <br/><br/>

Comment: Ok, now please update your _question_ with that information, and include the client-side `serviceModel` configuration.